# Is it possible to use Heroku Foreman with PHP?

Tags: php, heroku, foreman

I am developing a PHP app on Heroku.  Is it possible for me to use Foreman to test my application?  Everywhere I look I find references to Ruby, but nothing for PHP.

Comment: perhaps try this https://gist.github.com/anderssvendal/2585743

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using PHP 5.4 built-in web server:

```
sudo foreman start -f Procfile_dev
```

And in Procfile_dev:

```
web: php -S 127.0.0.1:80 -t /path/to/doc/root
```

This is how I develop locally. I also have a line `worker: watchr watcher.rb` that listens for file changes to combine/minify JS, compile SCSS, etc.

You could probably add `db: /usr/bin/mysqld` or similar to start mysql if need be.

ALSO: you'll want to install the [Heroku Config add-on](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-config), which will write the app config keys to a .env file that Foreman will send to php server on startup (accessible via getenv just like on Heroku.)